# Cordova advanced http error when load page without cordova.js

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, html-framework-7

I am having problems working with Cordova Advanced HTTP

https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http

When I first load the page I want to use Cordova Advanced HTTP to call the api on IOS device it gives me the following error

Cordova Advanced HTTP register unsuccessful:

[image]

Cordova Advanced HTTP register unsuccessful:

[image]

It seems to me that only after the page is loaded, the Cordova advanced http is ready to use.

Cordova Advanced HTTP register success:

[image]

but I need it to use the first time I call page. Is there a way to call it for the first time?
I have researched but have not found a solution, looking forward to hearing from everyone. Sorry my English is not good.

Comment: You are waiting for Cordova device ready event ?